# Implementing a method to be invoked based on an a separate value

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, abstract

What is the best way to run a method based on a variable that is not directly related to that method('s parameters).

For example, If I had an input that accepted Json or XML and I wished to parse this input using the correct method based on the type of the input (XML or Json), what possible ways could this be done?

Generally I would implement this as follow:

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(InputStream);
userInput= stream.ReadToEnd();

if (isJson(userInput))
{
    MethodA();
}
else
{
    MethodB();
}
```

However I don't like doing this as I feel it is a little immature and would much rather just do

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(InputStream);
userInput= stream.ReadToEnd();

//get input type and invoke correct method automatically
Method();
```

And let it work it out which to use automatically, I know I could do something like this with an abstract class and overrides, however I am not sure how I would initialise it based of a bool. Is this even possible? What if instead of a bool I had a more checks to run such as, if string =="a" do this, if string == "b" do this, if string == "C" do this, if string == "D" do this.

I am aware I could do this with some form of action map such as:

```
InputType inputType = getInputType(userInput);
Dictionary<InputType, Action> actionMap = new Dictionary<InputType, Action>();

actionMap.Add(InputType.Json, MethodA());
actionMap.Add(InputType.XML, MethodB());
actionMap.Add(InputType.Other, MethodC());

if (actionMap.ContainsKey(inputType))
{
   actionMap[inputType]();
}
```

But I equally don't like this way much, what other ways are there? I am really more interested in what people believe are the correct/most efficient/most advanced way of implementing this.

Comment: At the core of your problem, conceptually, there's no getting away from your first, simple example. Sure, you can wrap it up in all sorts of "mature" abstraction, but look at the unnecessary complexity that starts to grow. I'd stay away from the "most advanced" solution and strive for something simple and easy-to-understand, even if it's immature.

Comment: Don't over think it :) A switch statement would elegantly accomplish what need.

Comment: If you are only ever going to have JSON or XML as input types then perhaps a more "elegant" solution like the excellent factory method described in one of the answers is too much abstraction for such a simple scenario (although I'd personally probably do it anyways). However, if you could foresee more input types, then by all means, go for something higher level.

Comment: Yes, for such a simple true or false, an if-else seems most appropriate, I was just curious whilst coding if there was a more elegant way of handling it if I had many conditions. I will look into the factory methods and see if it is suitable for me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for, is for factory method. Using boolean checks obtained from string are not always the best. Get your desired concrete class by the conditions you choose, and then you'll only need to call

> factory.method()

Take a look at this wiki in order to get more clarified.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this, I will have a look into it for future reference, cheers!